# Post Two Forms From Same Webpage In Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I am creating a one page website using laravel where I have a login form and a registration form on the same page.

I wish to route them to their respective controller functions, say, `AccessController@login` and `AccessController@register` respectively.
How can I achieve this, when for both the forms the route would be:

```
Route::post('/', 'ControllerName@function')
```

Comment: The best way of doing this in my opinion would be to make separate endpoints for logging in and registering, as they are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a bad idea, but you can achieve what you want by doing this:

1. Add `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="register">` and `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">` to signup and login forms accordingly
2. In controller method check which form was submitted:

```
  $action = Input::get('action');

  // handle the register request
  if ($action === 'register') {
      return $this->register();

  // handle the login request
  } elseif ($action === 'login') {
      return $this->login();

  } else {
      throw new Exception("Unknown action");
  }
```

Comment: Is this the only way we can handle it in Laravel? Or are you talking PHP in general?

Comment: this is the general PHP way.

Comment: hence here you have two separate controller function, you can also create two forms with  two different action and submit them.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late. But if anybody looking for this.
Why don't you use like this?

first form

```
<form method="POST" name="login" id="login" action="{{ url('/login') }}">

</form
```

second form

```
<form name="register" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register')}}">

</form>
```

And in your route

```
Route::post('/login','AuthController@login');
Route::post('/register', 'AuthController@register');
```